# Commit the changes in eclipse to CVS

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I am sorry about my question. I have Googled but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

My code in code repository CVS. I have downloaded the code to my eclipse. When I commit the changes in eclipse it did not affect the code in CVS until I write `CVS update` command. I think there is some code need to be added to this file in `CVSROOT/loginfo`. Can you assist please?

Thanks,

Comment: It has been 8 years ago when I last used CVS, but I think commit should reflect your changes directly in the repo. After commit, check out the code in a temporal folder and please verify if the changes are there.

Comment: Thank you I got the issue solved myself and I edit my question with the answer

Comment: I rolled that change to the question back; answers go as answers (below the line) rather than in the question (above the line). It's the Stack Overflow way (and is SEO-optimized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should add this line to loginfo file:

```
^projectname (date; cat; (sleep 2; cd /data/www/projectname; cvs -q update -d) &)
```